# Assign row value of uipickerView to dynamically created uitextfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a booking app, where user can book a serviceName and servantName, i have to create dynamic (incremental) `UITextField`s for those two types, those `TextFields` get filled from Two `UIPickerView`s (PickerViews works fine).

How can i assign text to `TextFields`, which is dynamically created from those pickerViews.

I created `TextFields`s using `Autolayout` in `scrollView` as below function

```
func addBookingRow(firstTime: Bool)  {

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.backgroundColor = .white
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    containerView.layer.borderColor = .white
    containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    containerView.tag = count
    contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if firstTime {
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bookedServices[count - 1].bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

    let serviceNameTF = CustomTextField()
    serviceNameTF.backgroundColor = .white
    serviceNameTF.placeholder = "Choose Service"
    serviceNameTF.font = UIFont(name: "RB", size: 17)
    serviceNameTF.textAlignment = .right
    serviceNameTF.tag = count
    containerView.addSubview(serviceNameTF)
    setupPickerViews(textField: serviceNameTF, picker: serviceNamePicker)
    serviceNameTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.serviceNameIsTapped), for: .touchDown)
    serviceNameTF.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    serviceNameTF.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    serviceNameTF.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    serviceNameTF.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    serviceNameTF.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    let workerTF = CustomTextField()
    workerTF.backgroundColor = .white
    workerTF.placeholder = "Choose Servant"
    workerTF.font = UIFont(name: "RB", size: 17)
    workerTF.textAlignment = .right
    workerTF.tag = count
    containerView.addSubview(workerTF)
    setupPickerViews(textField: workerTF, picker: workerPicker)
    workerTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.workerTFIsTapped), for: .touchDown)
    workerTF.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    workerTF.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: serviceNameTF.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    workerTF.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    workerTF.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    workerTF.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    let price = UILabel()
    price.font = UIFont(name: "RB", size: 17)
    price.textColor = .white
    containerView.addSubview(price)
    price.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    price.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: workerTF.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    price.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    price.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    price.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: price.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: containerView.bottomAnchor,  constant: 250).isActive = true
    bookedServices.append(containerView)
    count += 1
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use a tableview rather than text fields in a scroll view.

Comment: tableView will make another effort because of dequeuing to collect data  after a scroll

Comment: How are you populating the picker views? Items from an array?

Comment: i have an extension, contains `pickerViews` and filled it from a api, everything works fine for `pickerViews`, but i can't assign text to `textFields`